# close a port with nodeJS

Tags: node.js

As I write a program that listen on a port, lets say 8081, and then write another program that listen on the same port I will get this type of error message:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039:14)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1127:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\NetBeansWorkPlace\nodeJS_Files\TutsNodeJS\static_file_server.js:36:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

I found that the port is in use but how can I clear the port, or stop the app from listening on a given port?

Comment: That depends entirely on how you are listening to that port.  I'm not sure how we are supposed to read your mind... care to post the code where you start your server on a port?

Comment: You want both to listen on the same port?

Comment: by the 6th line in your stackstace I assume you are running node from NetBeans IDE, if this is the case, you'll have to make sure you close the node process before starting a new one

Comment: If I run this simple code:
        
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'
    });
    
    res.end('Hello from HelloWorld.\n');
    
}).listen(9080, "");

 I will get the error message that port is un use when I run it a second time.

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE

So I would like to know how to stop listening to the port progromaticly or using the node command line.
        Thanks!

Comment: This article helped me resolve this issue  --  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437
TCPView v3.05
By Mark Russinovich
Published: July 25, 2011

Comment: Closing the listening process would free the port. Having two processes listen on the same port is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest approach is you can change the port number in your javascript file.

If you want to close the port simply do this (solution is for mac) open terminal

1) sudo lsof -i :

a table will be displayed look for PID in this table for your port

2) sudo kill -9 PID

Answer (score 3):

If you want that your node app will automatically close port 8081 before it's further processes start, you can use this trick.

1. Install the dependency :`npm i kill-port`
2. Now, import and run the code given below.

```js
const kill = require("kill-port");

kill(8080, "tcp");
```

With this, node will first clear the port connection at first so that you can go further with this port. And if the port is not open, then it will cause no harm.

Answer (score 1):

consult this  for a better understanding of this tool [fuser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_%28Unix%29)


fuser -k -n tcp portNumber

Answer (score 0):

Here are your options:

1- Exit the terminal you ran the node application from

2- Change the port number by editing the application

3- Use [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

4- [Kill the process](http://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-view-and-kill-processes-using-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x/) directly

I haven't tried the 4th option, but in theory it should work. Also, there are times when all of the above do not yield. That's where you would, logout, or restart your computer.